# Primefaces schedule component is not showing up

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces

I am a JSF 2.0 newbie, and I am trying to build an scheduler. 
So far everything has gone pretty well in terms of using primefaces and JSF tags. However I have a hard time using p:schedule tag. 
At the very list I just want the calendar (agenda) to show up in my page, before I move on to the next part and add events. 
My question is that shouldn't this code at least generate something in my page?

Here is my scheduleBean.java

```
 @ManagedBean(name="scheduler")
    @ViewScoped
    public class SchedulerBean extends PageCodeBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1426310201082465397L;
    private String loggedInUser;
    private boolean authorizeduser=false;
    private boolean showUnauthorizeduserMessage=true;
    private String theme;
    private AuthorizeduserManager AUM =  (AuthorizeduserManager)getManagedBean("AuthorizeduserManager");
    private ScheduleModel eventModel;

    public void pageOnLoad(){
        this.setLoggedInUser(getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
        this.checkAuthorization();
        this.retriveTheme();
        this.eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    }

    private void checkAuthorization(){
        ArrayList<Authorizeduser> athorizedUser= new ArrayList<Authorizeduser>();
        athorizedUser.addAll(AUM.getAuthorizeduser());
        for(Authorizeduser au:athorizedUser){
            if (loggedInUser.equalsIgnoreCase(au.getEmail())){
                setAuthorizeduser(true);
                showUnauthorizeduserMessage = false;
                return;
            }
        }   
    }//end checkAuthorization


    private void retriveTheme(){
        if(authorizeduser){
            this.theme = AUM.findAuthorizeduserByEmail(loggedInUser).getThemepref();
        }else{
            this.theme = "blitzer";
        }
    }


    private void persistTheme(String theme){
        //System.out.println("persistTheme was called");
        ArrayList<Authorizeduser> athorUser= new ArrayList<Authorizeduser>();
        athorUser.addAll(AUM.getAuthorizeduser());
        for(Authorizeduser au:athorUser){
            if (loggedInUser.equalsIgnoreCase(au.getEmail())){
                try {
                    au.setThemepref(theme);
                    AUM.updateAuthorizeduser(au);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }
        }
    }


    //Getters and setters
    public String getLoggedInUser() {
        return loggedInUser;
    }

    private void setLoggedInUser(String loggedInUser) {
        this.loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
    }

    public boolean isAuthorizeduser() {
        return authorizeduser;
    }

    private void setAuthorizeduser(boolean authorizeduser) {
        this.authorizeduser = authorizeduser;
    }

    public boolean isshowUnauthorizeduserMessage() {
        return showUnauthorizeduserMessage;
    }

    public void setshowUnauthorizeduserMessage(boolean showUnauthorizeduserMessage) {
        this.showUnauthorizeduserMessage = showUnauthorizeduserMessage;
    }

    public String getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme){
        this.theme = theme;
        this.persistTheme(theme);
    }   


     public String logout() {
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
         //System.out.println("logoutRequested");
         return "logout";
     }

    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        return eventModel;
    }

    public void setEventModel(ScheduleModel eventModel) {
        this.eventModel = eventModel;
    }


    }
```

here is my MasterLayout.xhtml

```
 <f:view>
    <!-- WelcomeBar -->
    <div id="WelcomeBar">
      <ui:include src="/resources/templates/WelcomeBar.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </div>


    <f:event listener="#{scheduler.pageOnLoad }" type="preRenderView"></f:event>



    <h:form styleClass="form" id="form1" height="30">
      <p:panel>

        <div id="Header">

          <ui:include src="/resources/templates/Header.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </div>


        <div id="content">
          <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="Footer">
          <ui:include src="/resources/templates/Footer.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </div>

      </p:panel>
    </h:form>
  </f:view>

</h:body>
```

And here is my schedule.xhtml which contain p:schedule tag:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    template="/resources/templates/MasterLayout.xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <!-- Content Properties  -->
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:schedule value="#{scheduler.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">
        </p:schedule>
    </ui:define>



</ui:composition>
```

Just FYI, I created a simple page text.xhtml, and it works. so it must be related to the way I am templating:

```
<h:body>
  <f:view>
    <h:form styleClass="form" id="form1" height="30">
      <p:panel>
          <f:event listener="#{scheduler.pageOnLoad }" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
          <h:outputText value="test"/>
          <p:schedule value="#{scheduler.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">
          </p:schedule>
      </p:panel>
    </h:form>
 </f:view>

</h:body>
```

Comment: you sure about that path? `template="/resources/templates/MasterLayout.xhtml"` ? also you better place the template into `/WEB-INF/templates/`

Comment: do you have an error? If you don't see anything, do you see something when your page is <ui:define name="content">
       <h:outputText value="test"/>
    </ui:define>

Comment: You mean, when you rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*, you're still seeing the unparsed `<p:schedule>` tag instead of its generated HTML representation? How about the `<p:panel>` which you've also there?

Comment: @Daniel  Yes everything works but p:schedule. I am able to see anything that I add under <ui:define> and I have different pages that use the template without any problem.

Comment: @roel no error, nothing just the fact that p:schedule doesn't show up. And yes I tried everything. It all works

Comment: @BalusC thanks for raising that point. This is what I see in the browser:
    <div id="content"><div id="form1:j_id2142848890_2_48117f8e"><div id="form1:j_id2142848890_2_48117f8e_container"></div></div><script id="form1:j_id2142848890_2_48117f8e_s" type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function() {PrimeFaces.cw('Schedule','myschedule',{id:'form1:j_id2142848890_2_48117f8e',defaultView:'month',locale:'en_US',offset:-18000000,header:{left:'prev,next today',center:'title',right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'}});});
//--></script>
        </div>

Comment: @thor I figured I should have eliminated unrelated stuff, but I tried it and it still didn't work ...

Comment: Okay, it generated the desired HTML. Now left behind potential JS errors. Do you have a `<h:head>` in the master template which allows JSF/PrimeFaces to auto-include CSS/JS stuff? Don't you see any JS errors in browser's JS console?

Comment: @BalusC great suggestion thanks. I never knew these existed. Yes I see this:  
Timestamp: 1/21/2013 10:48:34 AM
Error: ReferenceError: schedule is not defined
Source File: javascript:%20schedule
Line: 1

Comment: @BaluC YES!! the issue was with a single reference to jquery 
 type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascripts/jquery.js" in my schedule.xhtml. After I removed it, it all works great. More surprisingly, my jquery functions still work fine, so I really don't understand why this is happening. I checked the references and it seems right, so I have no idea, but I got what i needed!!